# wait until web pages fully load in java

Tags: java, netbeans, webdriver

i want to set a condition in my java program that util a web page fully loads no action will perform. i use explicit wait command and some other but these are not working good. when time finish next working starts. please help me if there is any other method. in Auto IT script it has a build in function to wait until page load. so is there any command like that. help me. i will very thank full to you.
Regards Muhammad Arslan

Answer (score 0):

In general, with Selenium 2.0 the web driver should only return control to the calling code once it has determined that the page has loaded.

Alternately you can use `implicitlyWait`, it will wait till the long the you mention in below code

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(long time, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit);
```

Example of above code:-

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

OR

If you want to wait for a specific element then you also use below code:-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, long timeOutInSeconds);

WebElement element = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(org.openqa.selenium.By locator))
```

Example of above code:-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='buttonGlbl']")));
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: thanks a lot Sir for your reply... This is very helpful for me

Comment: I appreciate Mr. Subhash's work. However, Implicitly wait does not really tells web driver that web page has fully loaded, it just waits till specified time or till web page is loaded in specified time period. There is no mechanism in the world to tell web page has loaded completely, you can just wait till specified time.